# I want to add a function to a button in django html such that when i click the button it adds +1 to the existing data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

[enter image description here][1]```py
def bunk(response):

```
def add_attend(x):
    x = x + 1

if response.method == 'POST':
    boonk = Bunk_calc(response.POST)
    if boonk.is_valid():
        class_attend = int(boonk.cleaned_data['class_attend'])
        total_attend = int(boonk.cleaned_data['total_attend'])
        subject = boonk.cleaned_data['subject']
        t = Bunk(class_attend=class_attend, total_attend=total_attend, subject=subject)
        min_attend = ceil(total_attend*0.75)
        percentage = (class_attend/total_attend)*100
        add_attend(class_attend)
        t.save()
```

I want to link this def add_attend to my button. How can I do that?

I want to link this def add_attend to my button. How can I do that?
I want to create a button "+1"beside the add button, which add +1 to the existing class_attend

Comment: Can you add more detail? You should also include your models.py, views.py, urls.py and the impacted html template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to achieve addition through Jinja and it's best to use Custom Template Tags in scenarios like this.
Create a templatetags directory under your Django App and add a custom_tags.py file.
Write your code in custom_tags.py:

```
@register.filter()
def add_attend(x):
    x = x + 1
    return x
```

In your HTML, first load the custom tags:

```
{% load custom_tags %}
```

Then you can use the custom tag appropriately whenever required, such as:

```
{{ 1|add_attend }}
```

Comment: how do i link this function to the button in my template

Comment: If you want to add integers, you don't really need to touch backend. Try writing a simple javascript function that does this for you.
Add HTML button:
`
<button type="button" onClick ="addInteger()" id="addBtn"> Add</button>
`
And in the end of your HTML page,  add:
`function addInteger(){yourvariable++;}`